# Gmaps4rails: What's the proper way to enable clustering after adding markers via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I tried to search the answer from docs, but couldn't find..

How can I enable clustering in Gmaps4rails when I add markers on the map via AJAX. My view has this:

```
<%= gmaps( map_options: { zoom: 15, auto_adjust: false } ) %>
```

and in my javascript I add the markers like this:

```
     $.getJSON(path, { lat: lat, lng: lng, user_lat: user_lat, user_lng: user_lng }, function(markers_json) {
        Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(markers_json); 
     });
```

I'd just like to set the do_clustering option to true, but because I don't have markers json in the map gmaps() call, I can't add the markers options either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell `gmaps4rails` directly:

```
Gmaps.map.markers_conf.do_clustering = true;
```

And include this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
```

Comment: It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined. I placed your code after my replaceMarkers.

Comment: my code should be added before yours. And I've updated my answer

Comment: Error message is gone, but I'm still unable to see any clustering happening. I'll try to debug a bit more in the evening. Maybe a bigger set of markers help me to test this thing. Btw. was that necessary js include tag mentioned somewhere in the wiki docs?

Comment: Add after the replace: `Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();`. All this is now automatic in the objectify_js branch on github

Comment: I didn't get your last comment. Anyway, clustering is now working. Just to make sure, does it matter where I include that clusterer js tag? Thanks again - really appriciate it.

Comment: was just talking about a new version I'll release soon and available on github. You can put the js tag anywhere before the gmaps4rails code

Comment: I have run on this question, and I was wondering where you got -1 :) and if the creator of gmaps4rails could get -1 for a question related to gmaps4rails then it is good that we others haven't tried at all :) we would get -10 :)

Comment: Sorry apneadiving mybad, I actually meant to upvote this yesterday and must have accidentally hit the down.  Now it wont let me fix it, it says it's locked unless the answer is edited.  Thanks for all you've done on this great gem!

Comment: @SteveO7: thanks for your comment, that's really nice from you :) Just edited the answer with a blank

Comment: By the way, I have the clustering working and I see that it is enabled by the markerclusterer library but I cant find where .markers_conf.do_clustering is documented.  Is that in the gem's code?

Comment: @SteveO7: defined here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/1.x/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee#L58 merged here https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/1.x/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee#L23